# Spivak Calculus Chapter 6 Exercise 9

Tags: calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta

The (a) part is clear:

> Suppose that $f$ is not continuous at $a$. Prove that for some number
> $\varepsilon>0$ there are numbers $x$ arbitrarily close to $a$ with
> $|f(x)-f(a)|>\varepsilon$.

It's not the case that $f$ continuous. Therefore it's not the case that $$\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,\forall x(|x-a|<\delta \rightarrow |f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon)$$

which is logically equivalent to

$$\exists\varepsilon>0,\forall\delta>0,\exists x(|x-a|<\delta \mbox{ and } |f(x)-f(a)|\geq\varepsilon)$$

There are $\varepsilon>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)|>\varepsilon$. Let $\varepsilon'=\frac12\varepsilon$. Then we have $|f(x)-f(a)|\geq\varepsilon>\varepsilon'$

The (b) part is not so much:

> Conclude that for some number $\varepsilon>0$ *either* there are
> numbers $x$ arbitrarily close to $a$ with $f(x)<f(a)-\varepsilon$ or
> there are numbers $x$ arbitrarily close to $a$ with
> $f(x)>f(a)+\varepsilon$

From (a) we have $|f(x)-f(a)|>\varepsilon$, which implies $f(a)-\varepsilon>f(x)>f(a)+\varepsilon$.

But $(f(a)+\varepsilon, f(a)-\varepsilon)=(-\infty,f(a)-\varepsilon) \cap (f(a)+\varepsilon,+\infty)$ is an empty set, $f(x)$ can't be in there.

How does it follow that that $f(x)\in (-\infty,f(a)-\varepsilon) \cup (f(a)+\varepsilon,+\infty)$?

Also it seems like a contradiction, does it mean that $f$ is actually continuous at $a$ (which is nonsense, all functions are continuous for all $a$)?

Comment: From $|f(x)-f(a)|>\varepsilon$, it follows that $f(x)>f(a)+\varepsilon$ or $f(x)<f(a)-\varepsilon$, where "or" is in the exclusive sense. By writing $f(a)-\varepsilon>f(x)>f(a)+\varepsilon$, you're saying that $f(x)>f(a)+\varepsilon$ and $f(x)<f(a)-\varepsilon$ are simultaneously true, which is not the case.

Comment: you're right, I've made a mistake there. Should have applied $|a|\geq b \rightarrow -a\leq b \mbox{ or } b \leq a$

Answer (score 0):

There exists a sequence of distinct points $x_n \to a$ such that $|f(x_n)-f(a)| >\epsilon$ for all $n$. The sets $\{n: f_n(x) >f(a)+\epsilon\}$ and $\{n: f_n(x) <f(a)-\epsilon\}$ cannot both be finite. (If they are both finite then $\mathbb N$ would be  a finite set). If there are infinitely many points in the first set then there are points arbitrarily close to $a$  with $f(x) >f(a)+\epsilon$. If there are infinitely many points in the second set then there are points arbitrarily close to $a$  with $f(x) <f(a)-\epsilon$.